# Get div starting position with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am building a drag and drop app. I am trying to get the starting position of the items to drag before they are moved.

When the app starts I am using '$(document).ready()', and then iterating through the elements. However, when this event is triggered, the left and top positions in the CSS don't seem to be set yet. Here is the code I am using to iterate:

```
var t;
$('.puzzle_piece').each(function(){
    t = $(this);
    t.startX = t.position.left;
    t.startY = t.position.top;
});
```

I have tried using 'position' and '.css('left')' to get the value.

One thing I noticed is that when I put an alert in there, the alert triggers BEFORE the layout even seems to start in the browser window.

How can I get the starting position of these elements?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The .puzzle_piece class is absolute, so each piece has the left and top set in the CSS.

Comment: `position().left` not `position.left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is a function. Use:

```
t.startX = t.position().left;
t.startY = t.position().top;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it relative to the document, then use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). Most likely this is the one you need.

If you want it relative to the offset parent (a parent element that has a position of `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute`), use [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/).